# Future Dragon Ball Super trailer analysis

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

This teaser trailer linked below was in my news feed this morning as I had my coffee.

I instantly spat it out after seeing a cameo from it.

Before reading any further to my actual question please watch the video to avoid spoilers.

https://youtu.be/Vr6e-amqTz0

Now, my question is: since the legendary super Saiyan appears and this is now canon, does that make Broly a canon character??

Comment: The question now could be. is Broly canon because of this? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/40292/will-the-new-dragon-ball-4d-broly-ssj3-vs-goku-ssj-blue-be-canon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion no, Broly can not be placed anywhere in the dbz manga story line, cause it would have been somewhere before the cell games. But yeah her transformation looks a lot like Broly. We should wait for more information, this could be a real "legendary" transformation or just something that resembles it. There is a lot of "fan fiction" that was taken from community response (like Veggetto) so that could be the case with the legendary transformation as well ( because it became iconic)

Comment: Yeah I suppose. But then again cannon works really weird in dbz. So I'll wait to see if any information relating to Broly comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Since they incorporated elements not created by Akira Toriyama and non canon into the series (final kamehameha from a videogame) and they re-used elements created in the series and not created by Akira Toriyama in the series (super saiyan blue kaioken), it's possible that they incorporate Broly story or part of its story into the series in the future, but it's not sure. I don't think they are planning to incorporate his movie story soon, since in episode 75 they had the chance to make him appear when Goku and Krilin met 10 villains from the past, and none of the bad guys from the movies were there. (Nor Cooler, Lord Slug, Broly, Janemba, Turles, etc.) .

On a sidenote, personally I think that the idea of someone being able to absorb the Genki Dama (Trunks in the battle against merged Zamasu) came from the movie Super Android 13 were Goku absorbed the Genki Dama for the first time, which it would be another element from non canon incorporated into the series as if it were canon, giving more clues indicating that they could incorporate something like part of Broly story into the series someday